# How to enable SPI1 and SPI0 at the same time?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, spi, c, c++

I have installed a **LCD screen** that use my SPI0 bus and I2C but i want to connect my **RFID reader** to the same raspberry. My lcd screen can you see here: https://www.adafruit.com/product/1601

SPI1 will not be enabled with SPI0, i have searched for Enable **SPI1** for raspberry Or Raspberry **SPI1**... But must results is links to enable SPI0 or SPI1 for python or SPI0 for c++

I want to use C++ as programming language. (you may send me C libarys but not Python)

This is the content of the raspberry file `/boot/config.txt`

```
https://pastebin.com/GrvAGzwx
```

Please tell me step 
**step-by-step** how you install SPI1 with SPI0 with C++

Can anybody help me please? Thank you. If you have the same problem please vote me.
If you fix how i can enable the SPI and wich libary support **SPI1** on **C++** or **C** then you figured out my problem.

Added:
Raspbian information:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.9.52-v7+ #1038 SMP Fri Sep 29 16:26:52 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Comment: Are you using Raspbian?  What does `uname -a` report?  What does `cat /etc/os-release` report.  **Edit the answers into your question.**

Comment: All you need to do is have the line `dtparam=spi=on` in `/boot/config.txt`.  I suspect the set-up for your LCD screen is claiming both SPI channels by mistake.  You could test by removing whatever you are using to set-up the LCD screen and seeing if the SPI devices then appear.

Comment: OK I go try it.

Comment: Okay, But i want that the LCD screen and RFID reader is working.
So i want to use SPI1. Not only LCD screen or RFID reader

Comment: if i go try with bcm2835 to connect to my rfid reader the lcd screen turns off.

Comment: You have not set if disabling the LCD allows the SPI devices to be seen at `/dev/spi*`.

Answer (score 5):

In order to use the spi1 port of the Raspberry Pi, you need to set the `dtoverlay=spi1-1cs` in `/boot/config.txt`. By default this will use the pins (https://pinout.xyz/pinout/spi):

- MOSI - pin 38
- MISO - pin 35
- CE0 - pin 12
- CLK - pin 40

You can change the CE0 pin (e.g. to pin 23) by adding `,cs0_pin=23` to the overlay. See `/boot/overlays/README` for more info.

Comment: It seems that `cs0_pin` can be any unused GPIO pin. It expects **BCM numbers only**. [source](http://terminal28.blogspot.com/2016/05/enabling-spi1-on-raspberry-pi-bzero23.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the tips.

In my case, just add this **dtoverlay=spi1-3cs** to /boot/config.txt and reboot

I changed too in the MFRC522 library the following parameter: **/dev/spidev0.0** to **/dev/spidev1.0**

In the pins were like this:

- SDA/CE2: 36
- MISO: 35
- MOSI: 38
- SCKL: 40
- RESET: 13

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone had the same problem, I had the same situation: using 3.5" LCD and MFRC522 at the same time. LCD driver is [this](https://github.com/lcdwiki/LCD-show) and MFRC522 driver is [this](https://github.com/pimylifeup/MFRC522-python).

I added this line at the end of config.txt and it worked!

It seems LCD driver claims GPIO7 & GPIO8 pins.

```
dtoverlay=spi1-3cs,cs0_pin=05,cs1_pin=06,cs2_pin=16
```