# is there a way to change SPI clock in shell or bash file?

Tags: pi-zero-w, spi, bash

I would like to write a bash to light up an OLED screen with SSD1306 driver, I can use below code to send commands:

```
echo -ne $cmd > /dev/spidev0.0
```

however the SPI clock seems too fast for SSD1306, is there a way to slowdown the clock (to like 4Mhz) in the shell? thanks for any advice, I am using pi zero W.

Comment: I used to use python to change SPI speed.  I found it easy.  I vaguely remember that I don't even need to reboot.  I used to use 400kHz and sometimes down to even 10kHz, without any problem.  BTW, your bash command doesn't seem to change the speed.

Comment: Details please.  Does the oled work at all?  Photos of the oled and wiring.  Are you sure it's not I2C?

Comment: hi Joan and tlfong01, thanks for comments. the OLED doesn't work at all, and yes it is SPI for sure, it works in my python code. I tried to adjust the clock in python, I found if I set to >16Mhz it will stop working, but works fine with clk lower than 16Mhz. the reason I want to use bash is because python is too slow at loading. what I want is user can see the display quickly after power up. any advice to achieve that?

Comment: If it doesn't work at all that doesn't prove it's a clock problem.  I't just as likely to be a problem with the commands you are sending via bash.  You need to add detail in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry it's not a complete answer, but my experience so far

- using the Python3 `spidev` library,

  - I can open `/dev/spidev0.0` or `/dev/spidev0.1`,
  - I can set the clock speed (noting that this is [not a precise frequency, but something like nearest power of two](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/spi/README.md))
  - I can write data, via Python or directly with `echo foo > /dev/spidev0.$N`
  - It comes out on BCM10, BCM11.
  - BCM7 or BCM8 are selected for each device, sounds like an active high.
  - I'm hearing it with a pair of headphones (not recommended!) because I have no better kit handy.
  - after calling the `close()` method on the SpiDev object, data is either not written to the port anymore with `echo` or it happens at a speed too fast to hear on headphones.
- I would guess that some kind of IOCTL call on the device sets the speed, and you might find this in the source for the Python library or the `.so` it calls.  Sorry I haven't looked for you.
- None of this is what I wanted, because I soldered my connector expecting to use the SPI1 bus on BCM20,BCM21...  a separate question.

I'm using a Pi Zero v1.3

Comment: my separate SPI1 bus question is https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/73346/how-to-enable-spi1-and-spi0-at-the-same-time/73844#73844

Comment: SPI isn't a secret.  The SPI chip select defaults to active low, i.e. if a chip is selected its chip select line will be held low.  An IOCTL is used to set the speed and perform the transfer, example C code at http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/code/spi-driver-speed.c

Comment: I know it's not a secret, but I haven't read *all* the docs.  I start with the obvious docs, then continue until I seem to have enough.

Answer (score 1):

Build (`make; sudo make install`) this [`ioctl`](https://github.com/jerome-pouiller/ioctl) tool. Then you should be able to issue IOCTL requests supported by the [SPI driver](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/spi/spidev):

> SPI_IOC_RD_MAX_SPEED_HZ, SPI_IOC_WR_MAX_SPEED_HZ ... pass a pointer to a
> u32 which will return (RD) or assign (WR) the maximum SPI transfer
> speed, in Hz.  The controller can't necessarily assign that specific
> clock speed.

If you happen to use more scripting languages than just BASH, there may be easier ways, e.g. in Perl:

```
require "sys/ioctl.ph";
ioctl(...);
```