# Connecting Two SPI LCD to raspberry pi GPIO pins

Tags: gpio, python, spi, pygame

I am doing my NEA project right now and I have a problem using 2 TFT LCD. Here are more details about the LCD 2.8" LCD SPI, Driver: ili9341 with touch version 1.2, this a picture of it:
[image]

I have connected the first LCD in the following Steps:

**Step 1:**

I connected the Screen to the GPIO to the following pin diagram:

```
Display GPIO #
VCC 3.3v
GND gnd
CS 8
RESET 27
DC 22
SDI(MOSI) 10
SCK 11
LED 13
```

**Step 2:**

I installed the tft9341 overlay:

```
git clone https://github.com/goodtft/LCD-show.git
cd LCD-show/
sudo cp ./usr/tft9341-overlay.dtb /boot/overlays/tft9341.dtbo
```

**Step 3:**

I updated the `/boot/config.txt` file

```
# turns spi on
dtparam=spi=on
# loads tft module for /dev/fb1
#
#dtoverlay=tft9341:rotate=270
dtoverlay=tft9341:rotate=270
# sets tft backlight pin on
gpio=13=op,dh
# or off at startup
#gpio=13=op,dl
```

and then restarted the Raspberry Pi and everything was working and the screen was connected to `/dev/fb1` and I was able to control the screen with pygame.

Now I want to control the second LCD at the same time.

If someone knows how to help me I would be grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how I did it
that's how I connected the screens to the Raspberry Pi:

[image]

Then execute this commands:

```
sudo pip3 install adafruit-circuitpython-rgb-display
sudo apt-get install fonts-dejavu
sudo apt-get install python3-pil
sudo apt-get install libopenjp2-7 libtiff5 libatlas-base-dev
pip3 install adafruit-blinka
```

this is for the coding for python
Now we need to enable the SPI
so to do that we need to execute this command

```
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

usually this line is commented so uncomment by simply removing the "#" before it
[image]
and add the following line also :

```
dtoverlay=spi1-1cs
```

then Ctrl+S and Ctrl+X
now if you want to check if everything is fine tell now:
execute the following command:

```
ls -l /dev/spi*
```

you should see this
[image]
and you can use this code it would work:

```
import time
import subprocess
import digitalio
import board
import busio
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
from adafruit_rgb_display import ili9341

cs_pin = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.CE0)
dc_pin = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D25)
reset_pin = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D24)
cs_pin1 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D18)
dc_pin1 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D26)
reset_pin1 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D6)

# Config for display baudrate (default max is 24mhz):
BAUDRATE = 24000000

# Setup SPI bus using hardware SPI:
spi1 = busio.SPI(board.SCK_1, MOSI=board.MOSI_1, MISO=board.MISO_1)
spi = busio.SPI(board.SCK, MOSI=board.MOSI, MISO=board.MISO)
                        # 0.96" SSD1331
disp = ili9341.ILI9341(
    spi,
    rotation=90,  # 2.2", 2.4", 2.8", 3.2" ILI9341
    cs=cs_pin,
    dc=dc_pin,
    rst=reset_pin,
    baudrate=BAUDRATE,
)
disp1 = ili9341.ILI9341(
    spi1,
    rotation=90,  # 2.2", 2.4", 2.8", 3.2" ILI9341
    cs=cs_pin1,
    dc=dc_pin1,
    rst=reset_pin1,
    baudrate=BAUDRATE,
)

if disp.rotation % 180 == 90:
    height = disp.width  # we swap height/width to rotate it to landscape!
    width = disp.height
else:
    width = disp.width  # we swap height/width to rotate it to landscape!
    height = disp.height

image = Image.new("RGB", (width, height))

# Get drawing object to draw on image.
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

# Draw a black filled box to clear the image.
draw.rectangle((0, 0, width, height), outline=0, fill=(0, 0, 0))
disp.image(image)
disp1.image(image)

# First define some constants to allow easy positioning of text.
padding = -2
x = 0

font = ImageFont.truetype("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf", 24)

while True:
    # Draw a black filled box to clear the image.
    draw.rectangle((0, 0, width, height), outline=0, fill=0)
    cmd = "hostname -I | cut -d' ' -f1"
    IP = "IP: " + subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).decode("utf-8")
    cmd = "top -bn1 | grep load | awk '{printf \"CPU Load: %.2f\", $(NF-2)}'"
    CPU = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).decode("utf-8")
    cmd = "free -m | awk 'NR==2{printf \"Mem: %s/%s MB  %.2f%%\", $3,$2,$3*100/$2 }'"
    MemUsage = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).decode("utf-8")
    cmd = 'df -h | awk \'$NF=="/"{printf "Disk: %d/%d GB  %s", $3,$2,$5}\''
    Disk = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).decode("utf-8")
    cmd = "cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp |  awk '{printf \"CPU Temp: %.1f C\", $(NF-0) / 1000}'"  # pylint: disable=line-too-long
    Temp = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).decode("utf-8")

    # Write four lines of text.
    y = padding
    draw.text((x, y), IP, font=font, fill="#FFFFFF")
    y += font.getsize(IP)[1]
    draw.text((x, y), CPU, font=font, fill="#FFFF00")
    y += font.getsize(CPU)[1]
    draw.text((x, y), MemUsage, font=font, fill="#00FF00")
    y += font.getsize(MemUsage)[1]
    draw.text((x, y), Disk, font=font, fill="#0000FF")
    y += font.getsize(Disk)[1]
    draw.text((x, y), Temp, font=font, fill="#FF00FF")

    # Display image.
    disp.image(image)
    disp1.image(image)
    time.sleep(0.0001)
```

this only works with the ili9341 driver display i am not aware of how I would do it with a different driver
But if you want to find out how to do it I used these websites:
-[enter link description here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-2-8-and-3-2-color-tft-touchscreen-breakout-v2/python-usage)
-[enter link description here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/73346/how-to-enable-spi1-and-spi0-at-the-same-time)
-[enter link description here](https://pinout.xyz/)
Here is a picture of it
[image]