# How to enable SPI1 and SPI0 at the same time on Linux?

Tags: pi-4, linux, spi, touchscreen

I'm trying this:
[How to enable SPI1 and SPI0 at the same time?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/73346/how-to-enable-spi1-and-spi0-at-the-same-time)
on Simply Linux 10.2 with Raspberry Pi 4 Model B. I want to use two touchscreens.

I'm adding dtoverlay=spi1-3cs to /boot/config.txt
I'm adding spi-bcm2711 to /etc/modules

But this is not enouth. The first touchscreen works, the second doesn't. Even if I connect it without the first one.

My touchscreen is 10.1 inch HDMI LCD with XPT2046 Touch Controller. I use pins MOSI, MISO, SCK, P6 and CE1. I conect LCD to Raspberry like this P6-GPIO18, SPI1 MISO-GPIO19, SPI1 MOSI-GPIO20, SPI1 SCLK-GPIO 21, CE1-GPIO22.

Comment: Did you read all of the answers to the Q&A you cited?

Comment: @Seamus yes. I have read and tried all the answers and comments.

Comment: What did you ACTUALLY do? What code are you attempting to run? Have you checked what devices are present? There is no need to load any modules and AKAIK what you loaded is wrong.

Comment: @Milliways I'm not trying to run code, I'm trying to connect two touchscreens to a Raspberry so that the sensors works for them. Now only one touchscreen works via SPI0.  I want to connect my second touchpad to SPI1 so that it works.